# Action dispatched automatically returns html response, but when run manually it returns JSON response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an action called `fetchUserPermissions` which returns a permission set from an api endpoint through axios. This action is run trough another action called init, which is run automatically trough the utility `dispatchActionForAllModules` which basically looks for the init action in all modules/submodules and runs it. This part seems to work fine, but it seems like the endpoint returns html (?) instead of a JSON response. The returned response looks something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <title>Title</title> </head> <body> <noscript> <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong> </noscript> <div id="app"></div> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://0.0.0.0:8080/bundle.js" ></script> </body> </html>
```

It's important to know that i run Vue through Django using the `webpack_loader` package. The above html is the index.html that serves Vue.

However, when i dispatch the action in the `created()` hook of an component it works as expected, and returns something like `{ "id": 1, "is_staff": true, "is_superuser": true, "permissions": [ "view_user" ], "group_permissions": [ "has_users_export" ] }`.

The `dispatchActionForAllModules` utility is basically copy paste from the vue-enterprise-bolierplate repo.

How can i make sure it returns a JSON response as expected?

**state/store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import dispatchActionForAllModules from '@/utils/dispatch-action-for-all-modules'
import modules from './modules'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules,
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
})

export default store

// automatically run the `init` action for every module,
// if one exists.
dispatchActionForAllModules('init')
```

**state/modules/index.js**

```
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

const modulesCache = {}
const storeData = { modules: {} }

;(function updateModules() {
  const requireModule = require.context(
    // Search for files in the current directory.
    '.',
    // Search for files in subdirectories.
    true,
    // Include any .js files that are not this file or a unit test.
    /^((?!index|\.unit\.).)*\.js$/
  )

  // For every Vuex module...
  requireModule.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
    const moduleDefinition =
      requireModule(fileName).default || requireModule(fileName)

    // Skip the module during hot reload if it refers to the
    // same module definition as the one we have cached.
    if (modulesCache[fileName] === moduleDefinition) return

    // Update the module cache, for efficient hot reloading.
    modulesCache[fileName] = moduleDefinition

    // Get the module path as an array.
    const modulePath = fileName
      // Remove the "./" from the beginning.
      .replace(/^\.\//, '')
      // Remove the file extension from the end.
      .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
      // Split nested modules into an array path.
      .split(/\//)
      // camelCase all module namespaces and names.
      .map(camelCase)

    // Get the modules object for the current path.
    const { modules } = getNamespace(storeData, modulePath)

    // Add the module to our modules object.
    modules[modulePath.pop()] = {
      // Modules are namespaced by default.
      namespaced: true,
      ...moduleDefinition,
    }
  })

  // If the environment supports hot reloading...
  if (module.hot) {
    // Whenever any Vuex module is updated...
    module.hot.accept(requireModule.id, () => {
      // Update `storeData.modules` with the latest definitions.
      updateModules()
      // Trigger a hot update in the store.
      require('../store').default.hotUpdate({ modules: storeData.modules })
    })
  }
})()

// Recursively get the namespace of a Vuex module, even if nested.
function getNamespace(subtree, path) {
  if (path.length === 1) return subtree

  const namespace = path.shift()
  subtree.modules[namespace] = {
    modules: {},
    namespaced: true,
    ...subtree.modules[namespace],
  }
  return getNamespace(subtree.modules[namespace], path)
}

export default storeData.modules
```

**state/modules/users.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = {
  requestUserPermissions: [],
}

export const mutations = {
  'FETCH_USER_PERMISSIONS' (state, permissions) {
    state.requestUserPermissions = permissions
  },
}

export const actions = {
  init: ({ dispatch }) => {
    dispatch('fetchUserPermissions')
  },
  fetchUserPermissions: ({ commit }) => {

    axios.get('user/permissions/').then(result => {
      console.log(result.data)
      commit('FETCH_USER_PERMISSIONS', result.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      throw new Error(`API ${error}`)
    })
  },
}
```

**utils/dispatch-action-for-all.modules.js**

```
import allModules from '@/state/modules'
import store from '@/state/store'

export default function dispatchActionForAllModules(actionName, { modules = allModules, modulePrefix = '', flags = {} } = {}) {
  // for every module

  for (const moduleName in modules) {
    const moduleDefinition = modules[moduleName]

    // if the action is defined on the module
    if (moduleDefinition.actions && moduleDefinition.actions[actionName]) {
      // dispatch the action if the module is namespaced, if not
      // set a flag to dispatch action globally at the end
      if (moduleDefinition.namespaced) {
        store.dispatch(`${modulePrefix}${moduleName}/${actionName}`)
      } else {
        flags.dispatchGlobal = true
      }
    }

    // if there are nested submodules
    if (moduleDefinition.modules) {
      // also dispatch action for these sub-modules
      dispatchActionForAllModules(actionName, {
        modules: moduleDefinition.modules,
        modulePrefix: modulePrefix + moduleName + '/',
        flags,
      })
    }
  }

  // if this is at the root ant at least one non-namespaced module
  // was found with the action
  if (!modulePrefix && flags.dispatchGlobal) {
    // dispatch action globally
    store.dispatch(actionName)
  }
}
```

The computed property in the component gets the data from store directly, like:

```
permissions() {
  return this.$store.state.users.requestUserPermissions
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the request, what is in the `Accept` header? When I have troubles like these, it is commonly because I forgot to request a json-format back, and it just defaults to html or no header at all.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. It's weird; dispatchig the action trough the `created()` hook, it returns `Accept: "application/json"` (which is defined as default in `main.js` through `axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json'`, however, when dispatching through the init action, it returns `Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"`. Do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. I usually just use a helper function that sets up the request instead of relying on the `axios.defaults`, so I have little experience with that.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I was getting html response when using
await axios.get('url'), I worked it out and changed it to
await this.$axios.get('url') and then I got the correct response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).